# How to get and save a graph from a URL that is not with graph extension

Tags: php, python

I have a url like this:

http://dcimg.awalker.jp/img2.php?sec_key=xZWxGNaeUCDrPK0RzhpTtodSJbErrouJoiYSlY64rQJUauCE7QiFuFGRLb493VcBPTpjJaWxFgkN8bROHj4tyKVy7NOXsLPYfAc1ZafxQsHhjCRSh1ZGfKiWSKEFGvpVr0begn1pypK14q4lwliYHPveVGcopU3Mc06eocNY3y1qGE0euUvPKaUQJty920CWiwEdMdLq

which opens as a graph, but no matter I used python or php curl or wget, I cannot get the graph and download it. Can you help to see how to get the content of the graph and save it? Thanks.

Comment: This URL actually leads to a blank page.  Is that why you're not getting anything?

Comment: I think to download any think from this site you need to login. And in your web browser you have already logged in so you are able to download. If this is the case you have to first login and use the session ID to download using any programming language